# How to generate URL using Module, controller and view?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Is there a way of generating a full url in zend if the Module, controller and view names are known?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I'm assuming you mean module, controller, and action, since the **view** is determined by the **action** (usually).*

**In the view**:

```
echo $this->url(array('module' => $module, 
                      'controller' => $controller, 
                      'action' => $action));
```

Any parameters not set, default to the current values, so in any given view:

```
echo $this->url(); //link for the current request
```

The function also accepts two additional arguments: `url($urlOptions, $name, $reset)`. `$name` allows you to specify a route name, and `$reset` will clear the generated URL of any current parameters.

**In the controller**:

This actually isn't documented, but follows the structure of the redirector helper (in fact, I believe it is used by the redirector helper):

```
$url = $this->getHelper('url')->simple($action, $controller, $module, $params);
```

You can also use the `url()` method, which follows the View helper:

```
$url = $this->getHelper('url')->url(array('module' => $module, 
                                          'controller' => $controller, 
                                          'action' => $action));
```

Comment: @Tobi - if it answers your question, hit the 'check-mark' to show that.

Comment: Worth adding that each of the vars module, controller and action are optional. If you omit them it'll default to the values in the page you're rendering it in.

Comment: @JamesC Indeed, I mentioned the reset flag, which clears that, but I'll update the answer so the default values are clear.